# How to fit the table in single beamer slide?

Tags: beamer

I have tried to use \small and \adjust commands, but could not get the desired result. Please help. The MWE is attached below.

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{EXata simulation parameters}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\label{tab-3.2:assumptions}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Interface} & \textbf{Parameter}            & \textbf{Value}                                                                 \\ \hline
    & Coordinate System             & Cartesian                                                                      \\
    & Grid Size (mxm)                    & 1500x1500                                                                      \\
    Terrain                  & Altitude Range (m)       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1500 (above sea level)\end{tabular}                                                         \\
    & Simulation length (s)   & 900                                                                            \\
    & Number of nodes               & 50, 75, 100, 150, 200                                                                   
    \\
    & Weather mobility (s)   & 100                         
    \\ \hline
    & Frequency (GHz)               & 2.4                                                                            \\
    Channel Properties       & Pathloss Model                & Two Ray                                                                        \\
    & Shadowing Model               & Log normal                                                                     \\
    & Shadowing Mean (dB)           & 5.8                                                                            \\ \hline
    & Radio Type                    & 802.15.4                                                                       \\
    & Transmission Power     & 3.0 dBm                                                                            \\
    & Packet Reception Model        & PHY802.15.4                                                                    \\
    Physical                 & Modulation Scheme             & O-QPSK                                                                         \\
    & CCA Mode                      & Carrier Sense                                                                  \\
    & Antenna Model                 & Omnidirectional                                                                \\
    & Noise Factor                  & 10.0                                                                           \\
    & Energy Model                  & MicaZ                                                                          \\ \hline
    & Protocol                      & 802.15.4                                                                       \\
    MAC                      & Device Type                   & FFD                                                                            \\
    & FFD Mode                      & PAN Coordinator                                                                \\ \hline
    Network                  & Protocol                      & IPv4                                                                           \\
    & Routing Protocol              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}AODV, Bellman Ford, \\Fisheye, Lanmar\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    & Mobility Model                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Random Waypoint\end{tabular}                                                                \\
    Mobility and Placement   & Pause Time (seconds)          & 10                                                                             \\
    & Node Orientation    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}azimuth=90, \\ elevation=70\end{tabular}            \\ \hline
    & Model                         & Linear                                                                         \\
    Battery Model            & Monitoring Interval (s) & 60                                                                             \\
    & Capacity (mAh)               & 1200                                                                           \\ \hline
    & Number of packets             & 1000                                                                           \\
    & Packet Size (bytes)           & 64                                                                             \\
    Application              & Start Time (seconds)          & 10                                                                             \\
    & End Time (seconds)            & 900                                                                            \\
    & Packet generation rate        & 100 packets/second \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Well, you *can* fit the table on one beamer frame but it becomes unreadable then. Do you think you will do yourself and your audience a favor when doing that?

Comment: Do ask yourself the following question: Do you really want to become known as "the guy who creates `beamer` presentations with utterly illegible tables that feature eight main categories, with each category featuring two to eight sub-categories"? Because that is, most assuredly, the *main impression* your audience will form during the presentation, and it will be the *only thing* your audience will remember from your presentation once two or three days have passed since the event...

Comment: Simply `\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering\tiny
\caption{EXata  .... ` fit the table, but I am with marmot and Mico. Is not a good idea. And please,  do not use [jailed tables](https://inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is very tall ... To fit it in one frame you should reduce its font size to `\tiny` and also reduce `\arraystretch` to 0.8 and omit frame title:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
%\frametitle{The table}
    \begin{table}
    \tiny
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
\caption{EXata simulation parameters}
\label{tab-3.2:assumptions}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Interface}  & \textbf{Parameter}    & \textbf{Value}    \\ 
    \midrule
Terrain   
    & Coordinate System         & Cartesian                             \\
    & Grid Size (m$\times$m)    & 1500$\times$1500                      \\
    & Altitude Range (m)        & 1500 (above sea level)                \\
    & Simulation length (s)     & 900                                   \\
    & Number of nodes           & 50, 75, 100, 150, 200                 \\
    & Weather mobility (s)      & 100                                   \\
    \addlinespace[2pt]
Channel Properties
    & Frequency (GHz)           & 2.4                                   \\
    & Pathloss Model            & Two Ray                               \\
    & Shadowing Model           & Log normal                            \\
    & Shadowing Mean (dB)       & 5.8                                   \\
    \addlinespace[2pt]
Physical 
    & Radio Type                & 802.15.4                              \\
    & Transmission Power        & 3.0 dBm                               \\                                                                            & Packet Reception Model    & PHY802.15.4                           \\
    & Modulation Scheme         & O-QPSK                                \\
    & CCA Mode                  & Carrier Sense                         \\
    & Antenna Model             & Omnidirectional                       \\
    & Noise Factor              & 10.0                                  \\
    & Energy Model              & MicaZ                                 \\
    \addlinespace[2pt]
MAC & Protocol                  & 802.15.4                              \\
    & Device Type               & FFD                                   \\
    & FFD Mode                  & PAN Coordinator                       \\ 
    \addlinespace[2pt]
Network             
    & Protocol                  & IPv4                                  \\
    & Routing Protocol          & AODV, Bellman Ford, Fisheye, Lanmar   \\
    \addlinespace[2pt]
Mobility and Placement
    & Mobility Model            & Random Waypoint                       \\
    & Pause Time (seconds)      & 10                                    \\
    & Node Orientation          & azimuth:~90, elevation:~70            \\
    \addlinespace[2pt]
Battery Model   
    & Model                     & Linear                                \\
    & Monitoring Interval (s)   & 60                                    \\
    & Capacity (mAh)            & 1200                                  \\ 
    \addlinespace[2pt]
Application
    & Number of packets         & 1000      \\
    & Packet Size (bytes)       & 64        \\
    & Start Time (seconds)      & 10        \\
    & End Time (seconds)        & 900       \\
    & Packet generation rate    & 100 packets/second \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Another options is to split table into two parts and with use `\footnotesize` font size make it more readable. With this table is placed on two slides in frame (what you not like to do, however anticipate audience filling when looks almost unreadable table):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{The table}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.85}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\caption{EXata simulation parameters (first part)}
\label{tab-3.2:assumptions}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Interface}  & \textbf{Parameter}    & \textbf{Value}    \\
    \midrule
Terrain
    & Coordinate System         & Cartesian                             \\
    & Grid Size (m$\times$m)    & 1500$\times$1500                      \\
    & Altitude Range (m)        & 1500 (above sea level)                \\
    & Simulation length (s)     & 900                                   \\
    & Number of nodes           & 50, 75, 100, 150, 200                 \\
    & Weather mobility (s)      & 100                                   \\
    \addlinespace
Channel Properties
    & Frequency (GHz)           & 2.4                                   \\
    & Pathloss Model            & Two Ray                               \\
    & Shadowing Model           & Log normal                            \\
    & Shadowing Mean (dB)       & 5.8                                   \\
    \addlinespace
Physical
    & Radio Type                & 802.15.4                              \\
    & Transmission Power        & 3.0 dBm                               \\                                                                            & Packet Reception Model    & PHY802.15.4                           \\
    & Modulation Scheme         & O-QPSK                                \\
    & CCA Mode                  & Carrier Sense                         \\
    & Antenna Model             & Omnidirectional                       \\
    & Noise Factor              & 10.0                                  \\
    & Energy Model              & MicaZ                                 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\framebreak
    \begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.85}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\caption{EXata simulation parameters (second part)}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Interface}  & \textbf{Parameter}    & \textbf{Value}    \\
    \midrule
MAC & Protocol                  & 802.15.4                              \\
    & Device Type               & FFD                                   \\
    & FFD Mode                  & PAN Coordinator                       \\
    \addlinespace
Network
    & Protocol                  & IPv4                                  \\
    & Routing Protocol          & AODV, Bellman Ford, Fisheye, Lanmar   \\
    \addlinespace
Mobility and Placement
    & Mobility Model            & Random Waypoint                       \\
    & Pause Time (seconds)      & 10                                    \\
    & Node Orientation          & azimuth:~90, elevation:~70            \\
    \addlinespace
Battery Model
    & Model                     & Linear                                \\
    & Monitoring Interval (s)   & 60                                    \\
    & Capacity (mAh)            & 1200                                  \\
    \addlinespace
Application
    & Number of packets         & 1000      \\
    & Packet Size (bytes)       & 64        \\
    & Start Time (seconds)      & 10        \\
    & End Time (seconds)        & 900       \\
    & Packet generation rate    & 100 packets/second \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

the height of ~ 3cm is commented out i would split the table or remove the title:

````
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{beamer}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{frame}
%\frametitle{This is a frame with a table}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{EXata simulation parameters}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\label{tab-3.2:assumptions}
%\resizebox{\linewidth}{3cm}{% i would split it up
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Interface} & \textbf{Parameter}            & \textbf{Value}                                                                 \\ \hline
    & Coordinate System             & Cartesian                                                                      \\
    & Grid Size (mxm)                    & 1500x1500                                                                      \\
    Terrain                  & Altitude Range (m)       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1500 (above sea level)\end{tabular}                                                         \\
    & Simulation length (s)   & 900                                                                            \\
    & Number of nodes               & 50, 75, 100, 150, 200                                                                   
    \\
    & Weather mobility (s)   & 100                         
    \\ \hline
    & Frequency (GHz)               & 2.4                                                                            \\
    Channel Properties       & Pathloss Model                & Two Ray                                                                        \\
    & Shadowing Model               & Log normal                                                                     \\
    & Shadowing Mean (dB)           & 5.8                                                                            \\ \hline
    & Radio Type                    & 802.15.4                                                                       \\
    & Transmission Power     & 3.0 dBm                                                                            \\
    & Packet Reception Model        & PHY802.15.4                                                                    \\
    Physical                 & Modulation Scheme             & O-QPSK                                                                         \\
    & CCA Mode                      & Carrier Sense                                                                  \\
    & Antenna Model                 & Omnidirectional                                                                \\
    & Noise Factor                  & 10.0                                                                           \\
    & Energy Model                  & MicaZ                                                                          \\ \hline
    & Protocol                      & 802.15.4                                                                       \\
    MAC                      & Device Type                   & FFD                                                                            \\
    & FFD Mode                      & PAN Coordinator                                                                \\ \hline
    Network                  & Protocol                      & IPv4                                                                           \\
    & Routing Protocol              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}AODV, Bellman Ford, \\Fisheye, Lanmar\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    & Mobility Model                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Random Waypoint\end{tabular}                                                                \\
    Mobility and Placement   & Pause Time (seconds)          & 10                                                                             \\
    & Node Orientation    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}azimuth=90, \\ elevation=70\end{tabular}            \\ \hline
    & Model                         & Linear                                                                         \\
    Battery Model            & Monitoring Interval (s) & 60                                                                             \\
    & Capacity (mAh)               & 1200                                                                           \\ \hline
    & Number of packets             & 1000                                                                           \\
    & Packet Size (bytes)           & 64                                                                             \\
    Application              & Start Time (seconds)          & 10                                                                             \\
    & End Time (seconds)            & 900                                                                            \\
    & Packet generation rate        & 100 packets/second \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}```
````